# salesforce lightning: you need permission to refresh this dashboard

Tags: dashboard, salesforce-lightning

I have created 1 dashboard with 4 summary reports as a system administrator. For custom Profile, I have given reports & dashboard folder access "Can Manage".

Now when user of that custom profile, is trying to view that dashboard, getting error as "You need permission to refresh this Dashboard".
Whereas, he can view all the 4 reports with correct data loaded in it.

Please help me to figure out what am I missing in this implementation.

Thanks in advance!
Priyanka

Comment: I'm facing this problem on dashboards that have the new Lightning Dashboard Tables added to them.

Comment: I don't think this is a recommended solution, but when I gave the running user's profile the  'Create and Customize Dashboards' permission, this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to classic and refresh in classic. The refresh will then work in Lightning as well.